# Excel (google sheets) using LINEST formula

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to copy this example from this URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moHQMBPFhbQ

Formula
Y = 0,3x^4 - 2,8x^3 + 3,4x^2 + 5,7x - 6,6

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0,0 |
| 2 | 0,8 |
| 3 | −10,2 |
| 4 | −31,8 |
| 5 | 55,6 |
| 6 | −66,0 |
| 7 | −40,2 |
| 8 | 51,8 |
| 9 | 247,2 |
| 10 | 590,4 |

I am typing the same formulas as in the link
(one difference, replacing "," with ";" since im running it in google sheets)

| =ArrayFormula(LINEST(C7:C15;B7:B15^{1;2;3;4})) |
| --- |
| #SAKNAS! (#NA) |

However, when I ad the same size of the polynom as rows i get values at least

| =ArrayFormula(LINEST(C6:C15;B6:B15^{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10})) |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0,00000005788707375 | 19,52808693 |

All help is appreciated, does it work on your machine?
Does this error occurs because i'm using ";"

( "," is not working either, my version interpret it as ".")

Answer (score 0):

The array literal `{1,2,3,4}` in that YouTube video is a row of data and the comma separates the columns. Your `{1;2;3;4}` is a column of data and the semicolon separates rows. That cannot work.

If you get the `Google Sheets` help using keyword `array` you get:

[**Using arrays in Google Sheets**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en-GB)

> ...
>
> **Create arrays** You can also create your own arrays in a formula in your spreadsheet by using brackets { }. The brackets allow you to
> group together values, while you use the following punctuation to
> determine which order the values are displayed in:
>
> **Commas**: Separate columns to help you write a row of data in an array. For example, ={1, 2} would place the number 1 in the first cell
> and the number 2 in the cell to the right in a new column.
>
> **Semicolons**: Separate rows to help you write a column of data in an array. For example, ={1; 2} would place the number 1 in the first cell
> and the number 2 in the cell below in a new row.
>
> **Note**: For countries that use commas as decimal separators (for example €1,00), commas would be replaced by backslashes (\) when
> creating arrays.
>
> ...

So, since your `Google Sheets` is using commas as decimal separators, you need to follow the note.

Following formula works for me:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LINEST(B2:B11;A2:A11^{1\2\3\4}))
```

But to constrain the result to correct size (1 row, 5 columns) you should wrap that into `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(LINEST(B2:B11;A2:A11^{1\2\3\4}));1;5)
```

This is what `Google Sheets` creates automatically when it opens a `Microsoft Excel` sheet having the formula `=LINEST(B2:B11,A2:A11^{1,2,3,4})`.